# Docker volume mariadb has root permission

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, mariadb, permission-denied

I stumbled across a problem with docker volumes while starting docker containers with a docker compose file (MariaDB, RabbitMQ, Maven). I start them simply with `docker-compose up -d` (WITHOUT SUDO)

My volumes are definied like this:

```yaml
...
volumes:
  - ./production/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:z
...
```

Everything is working fine and the `./production` directory is created (where the volumes are mapped)

But when I again try to restart the docker containers with down/up, I get following error:

```sh
error checking context: 'no permission to read from '…/production/mysql/aria_log.00000001'
```

When I check the mentioned file I saw that it needs root:root permission. This is because the file is generated with the root user inside the container. So I tried to use namespace as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/).

Anyway the error still occurs. Any ideas or references?

Thanks.

Docker Compose File:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - config.env
    volumes:
      - ./production/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:z
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - testnetwork

networks:
  testnetwork:
```

Comment: Don't forget to delete the file and let the container re-create it. Or give it ownership equal to the mapped root user. If the file was created with the host's root, the user namespace mapped root won't have permissions to it; they're a different user ID and the permissions mask will fail verification.

Comment: @edd Yes I deleted them. Giving the same ownership equal to the mapped root user would be my prefered solution. Do you have any reference or guide regarding that?

Comment: What are the file ownerships on the host? Are you using user namespaces? Is this on RHEL, Docker for Mac, describe your host. Most importantly, do you even need host access to these files, why not use a named volume?

Comment: @BMitch on the host system the file ownership is `root:root`. Yes I also tried namespaces then they have the configured uid/gid. Anyway I get the same error. No I don't need to access those files, so I could use named volumes. I just wanted it in a directory as a simplification to have everthing in place.

Comment: What do you mean with the *wihtout sudo* are using rootless docker or is your user a member of the `docker` group. 

What does `grep docker /etc/group` show you ? Does it show your user ?

Comment: My user is a member of the docker group. So indirectly without sudo. I know that the containers are still launched as sudo. Only if I use rootless docker it would be really rootless.

Comment: Can you please share with us the docker-compose file, in order to test in my environment ?

Comment: @Iduoad updated my question with an example docker compose file.

Comment: When I tested in my env and in docker playground, it worked! The mariadb container does create the log files under the mysql user (999:999). From outside the container here is what I get `-rw-rw----    1 999      ping        417792 Jan  6 16:04 aria_log.00000001` which is equivalent to 999:999 in the host.

Comment: What does `ls -al production/mysql` give you in the host?

Comment: I do not get it. The docker daemon always runs as the root user. If you don’t want to use sudo when you use the docker command, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. Your user is member of the docker group. Therefore, it starts with sudo even if you do not type sudo. Why do you then say that you start it indirectly without sudo? I would say you start it indirectly *with* sudo. And the error is then astonishing. Did you add your user correctly with `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`? From: https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Answer (score 4):

The issue comes from the mapping between the host user/group IDs and the ones inside the container. One of the solutions is to use a named volume and avoid all this hassle, but you can also do the following:

Add `user: ${UID}:${GID}` to your service inside the docker-compose file.
Run `UID=${id -u} GID=${id -g} docker-compose up`. This way you make sure that the user in the container will have the same UID/GID as the user on the host and files created in the container will have proper permissions.

**NOTE:** Docker for Mac (using the `osxfs` driver) does this behind the scenes and you don't need to worry about users and groups.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Docker daemon as a non-root user this can be helpfull for your purpose.

all document are [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/).